# What is a standard way to do autocomplete of addresses from DB?

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, autocomplete

I am having DB table with various addresses. It is divided into fields `Street Name`, `House Number`, `Floor Number`, `Door Number`.

I need to do autocomplete field (only one search field is there, consisting all fields mentioned above), which would suggest all matching addresses while typing.

Normally I would split it by space and have it done. 
However, how do you do it if `Street Name` sometime consists of 1,2,3 or more words?

Comment: Mandatory read: https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/ => addresses are hard.

Comment: You don't want to be running search queries against your database after every keystroke. Well, maybe you do, but your users certainly don't want you to do that.

Comment: How come not? I mean it is like that in google maps as well... lets say after 4th character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QAS PAF Matching Software has a whole team dedicated to finding address algorithms, and have been working on it for decades, and they still don't get it 100% of the time. Unless Jesus lives in Stack Overflow, I'm afraid you won't find anyone here who can solve your query out-of-the-box with SQL Server. Leading experts will tell you, this is something people will avoid like the plague, and spend tens of thousands of pounds per year to outsource to other companies.

Comment: If you really want to lose your hair though, take a look at this: http://anastasiosyal.com/POST/2009/01/11/18.ASPX?

Comment: Actually I have found kind of solution and that is to put another column to database containing full address and check on it. If it contains searched address or not. It will work only if user will keep order street, number, floor, house number ... but that should be enough. :)

Comment: If that's sufficient for your needs then by all means. I have used this kind of distance calculation before to find close matching data, but not on addresses, as I found it to be a nightmare, and the odd record here and there matched higher than the actual correct match intended. I guess the answer is to make multiple passes with each distance calculation to create a mean average match rate, and based on that you will have a good chance of matching the correct address.